# Всплывающее окно в Android Studio

Tags: android

[image: пример]

Как сделать всплывающее окно, которое затемнит/размоет фон activity, из которого оно было вызвано и сможет содержать полноценное оформление. Если все дело в xml разметке, то что там прописать, чтбы ддобиться такого эффекта?

Comment: это называется `AlertDialog`, можно через `DialogFragment`, смотрите в эту сторону. Почитайте и пишите если появятся конкретные вопросы конкретной реализации

Comment: Вопрос к Андроид Студии не относится...

Answer (score 2):

**Создаете dialogFragment класс.**

```
public class DialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Title: ")
               .setIcon(XXXX);
               .setMessage("...");
        return builder.create();
    }


}
```

**Вызывается таким образом.**

```
DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();                                  
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```